# Should the glymphatic system be covered by extending the lymphatic system tag? Does it warrant a separate tag? Neither?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging, tag-management

Wikipedia's Glymphatic system includes the following:

> Glymphatic flow was initially believed to be the complete answer to the long-standing question of how the sensitive neural tissue of the CNS functions in the perceived absence of a lymphatic drainage pathway for extracellular proteins, excess fluid, and metabolic waste products. However, two subsequent articles by Louveau et al. from the University of Virginia School of Medicine and Aspelund et al. from the University of Helsinki **reported independently that the dural sinuses and meningeal arteries are lined with conventional lymphatic vessels, and that this long-elusive vasculature forms a connecting pathway to the glymphatic system.**<sup>4,5</sup>
>
> <sup>4</sup>Louveau A, Smirnov I, Keyes TJ, Eccles JD, Rouhani SJ, Peske JD, et al. (July 2015). "[Structural and functional features of central nervous system lymphatic vessels](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4506234)". Nature. 523 (7560): 337–41.
>
> <sup>5</sup>Aspelund A, Antila S, Proulx ST, Karlsen TV, Karaman S, Detmar M, et al. (June 2015). "[A dural lymphatic vascular system that drains brain interstitial fluid and macromolecules](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4493418)". The Journal of Experimental Medicine. 212 (7): 991–9.

I don't have the background to just how to tag the only (currently at least) question about the glymphatic system:

- [How widespread among mammals is the glymphatic system's metabolite clearance in the brain during sleep currently known to be?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/107737/27918)

so I thought I would just raise the issue here.

**Question:** Should the glymphatic system be covered by extending the lymphatic system tag? Does it warrant a separate tag? Neither?

The "Neither?" indicates that it's not necessarily a binary choice of one or the other; perhaps this system is too obscure to be addressed in tags at all? It seems that mine is the first question that contains "glymphatic".